# Laravel 5.7.x Validator Errors not showing in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I know this question has been asked about earlier versions of Laravel, but I"m using 5.7.x (the latest) and what worked in 5.2 might not be applicable in my case. Basically, I'm trying to create a Post form validated by a custom FormRequest. Here are my source files.

post.create.blade.php

```
<html>
    @include('header')
    <body>
        <h1>Add a New Post</h1>

        {!! Form::open(['route' => 'save_post']) !!}
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', null) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:') !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('body', null) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::submit('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-info']) !!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @if($errors->any())
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('post/create', function () {
return view('post_create');
});
```

PostController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Post;
use App\Http\Requests\PostCreateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Post::paginate(1);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        return Post::find($id);
    }

    public function store(PostCreateRequest $request)
    {        
        $post = Post::create($request->all());
        $post->save();

        return response()->json($post, 201);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->update($request->all());
        return response()->json($post, 200);
    }

    public function delete(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->delete();
        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
```

PostCreateRequest.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
class PostCreateRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'body' => 'required|string|max:4096'
        ];
    }
}
```

Clearly the validator is working. When I fill out the name and body, it adds a post to the SQL database on the backend. And when it fails, it goes back to the post create view. The problem is that the validator errors don't show up in the view even though I have it coded in. What exactly is going on? Is there some sort of bug in Laravel?

UPDATE: Oh, and in case anyone's curious, I'm using Ubuntu. Some sources suggest this used to matter before. I'm not sure if it still does.

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce this on a fresh Laravel install. Is `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` commented in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file in the `web` middleware group by any chance?

Comment: It isn't. Should it be?

Comment: I guess not. I just tried commenting it out and it threw the exception ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: errors

Comment: This is very weird. Did you try to add validations directly from the controller ?

Comment: If you're talking about the Validator::make method, then yes I did. And it still failed.

Comment: Did you add the `Route::post('save_post)` in your web.php ?

Comment: Also, do you not need the CSRF token in your form?

Comment: Oh yeah, there is a save_post. Does the CSRF not come with the Form:: class? I thought it did.